# sending data to bluetooth module to be read by arduino rom iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, hm-10

If i want to send data to a bluetooth module, which is connected to the Arduino, what code lines are specifically the ones I need to take notice of.

I want to send something like, the number '75' to the bluetooth module and the Arduino will read it

thanks

Comment: You can only do this with Bluetooth LE in iOS and you need to know the peripheral id, the service and the characteristic.  I think you need to do more research on the basics of BluetoothLE and come back with a more specific questions.  there are apps like Light Blue explorer that will discover peripherals, services and characteristics so you can make sure the arduino is publishing this information before you start on the iOS code.

Comment: I have done all of that. The only bit I lack is how to send the data across...I have searched in here for an answer but can't seem to find one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth LE is very long and cumbersome with many delegates in between.  The minimum path to write your data is:

1. Make sure you have bluetooth permission: CBCentralManagerDelegate.centralManagerDidUpdateStateand if so start scanning with scanForPeripherals
2. CBCentralManagerDelegate.didDiscover If this is the peripheral you want then set yourself as its delegate
3. CBPeripheralDelegate.peripheral:didDiscoverServices: If this is the service you want then stop scanning and discoverCharacteristics:for: service
4. CBPeripheralDelegate.peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor: service If a characteristic in the array of characteristics is the one you want then:

   ```
   func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
       guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
           return
       }
       for characteristic in characteristics {
           if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: characteristicIdentifier) {
               let value: UInt8 = 75
               let data = Data(bytes: [value])
               peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Josh, this is what I needed

Comment: If i want it such that i press a button, then it send the number 75, how would that work?

Comment: You need to hang on to the peripheral and the characteristic from their respective delegates and then write the characteristic to the peripheral in the button handler.